# Can you leave your base without being spotted in Dominion?

Tags: league-of-legends

If you play Dominion a few times, you'll spot narrow strips of "fog of war" that lead from your base's ramps towards the center of the map. Are they wide enough that you can travel along them to reach the "jungle" (such as it is) without being spotted on the minimap?

Or has there been no point to my religiously sticking to the shadows, as my enemies can see me anyways?

Edit: It still looks extremely narrow - any known tricks for making sure you stay inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can by being in the fog of war, but you have to keep to the one side of it if you don't want to be spotted.

Comment: Are there any known tricks for making sure you stay inside? I can imagine even the tiniest misclick rendering you visible. Sometimes I see enemies on the minimap that appear to otherwise be in the narrow area.

Comment: Not really you just have to get thee feel of it

Comment: I'd like to click the checkmark... but can I beg you pretty please to clarify what you mean by "the one side"? Then I swear I'll stop asking questions. Thanks, and apologies if I am being frustrating.

Comment: I suggest sticking to the side that is farther from the place were the enemies are and that way you can jump jump out and back in if the they see you and go after you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. The small corridors of Fog of War leading from the ramps to the inner ring of fog of war exist for exactly this purpose.